# Unzip gzip file and accept the name of the file that is included in the actual zip

Tags: file, powershell, unzip, gzip

I am using the script I found to natively inzip .gz file, and it works fine. the script as follows:

```powershell
Function DeGZip-File{
    Param(
        $infile,
        $outfile       
        )

    $input = New-Object System.IO.FileStream $inFile, ([IO.FileMode]::Open), ([IO.FileAccess]::Read), ([IO.FileShare]::Read)
    $output = New-Object System.IO.FileStream $outFile, ([IO.FileMode]::Create), ([IO.FileAccess]::Write), ([IO.FileShare]::None)
    $gzipStream = New-Object System.IO.Compression.GzipStream $input, ([IO.Compression.CompressionMode]::Decompress)

    $buffer = New-Object byte[](1024)
    while($true){
        $read = $gzipstream.Read($buffer, 0, 1024)
        if ($read -le 0){break}
        $output.Write($buffer, 0, $read)
        }

    $gzipStream.Close()
    $output.Close()
    $input.Close()
}

$infile="dir\somename.gz"
$outfile="dir\newname.txt"

DeGZip-File $infile $outfile
```

The issue is that the file name inlcuded in .gz is different from the input file somename.gz, and I need to accept the included name to be as an output name, but cannot find a solution. If I fully qualify the outfile name (path+name), script works. But i want to be able to just simply unzip the input file and accept the file name included

And one more thing, this function must be executed within vbs file.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking for. Do you want the output file to have the same name as the zip file automatically as supposed to having to supply it? Also the last sentence is not just a quick side note. Would think you need to convert the function to a standalone script that you could call in vbs with `WshShell.Run`

Comment: The last part figured out. But let me explain the main issue. If I use winzip for example, then the file name is different from the input file name, and I want that name to be the output name. Let's try with and example: input file name is called file1.gz. Using winzip to decompress the file it will show up as myfile.txt. And I want that name myfile.txt to be in the output destination. You might ask why? Every week the file name changes, but the .gz file is always the same. That is why I can hard code the input name, but not the output. I hope it is a bit clearer.

Comment: Does that mean the vbs portion of this question is not important? If that is the case please edit the question and remove that sentence.

Comment: So your zip contain one txt file but you dont know what the name is since it will not match the zip name. You want the output file to have the name of the compressed file without hardcoding it? I think i get it.

Comment: Yes. And by the way whey I tried to run the ps1 file within vbs, it does not work. That is what I have: Dim objShell
Dim objResult
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") objShell.Run "cscript d:\myscript.ps1", 1, True
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Comment: vbs question is important, I created the separate file as .ps1 file, then called it within vbs with objShell.run("powershell -noexit -file command, but the window for powershell stays open even after the file is unzipped

Comment: I suggest making another question for the VBS component once the zip issue is addressed. You are asking about 2 different problems in one question. In your example you are telling PowerShell to stay open with `-noexit`